# UITableView with dynamic height in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, xcode-6.2

I would like to create a dynamically sized UITableView in Swift.
When I add a UITableView via the storyboard some content is cut off at a certain point.

Is there a way to make it possible to scroll through the content without cutting off any of it? I've thought about adding a UIScrollView, but this kind of view seems to be used for something else (e.g.: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift )

At best I'd like to have a scrollable UITableView that almost fills the screen and a button that always stays on the very bottom.

Edit - To clarify what I meant by cutting off: When there are e.g. 100 elements in an array, only 10 were displayed.

But the concept of placeholder constraints solved this issue, since my array length is determined during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a dynamically sized UITableView, use AutoLayout. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Yes its possible to not cut your content, but how is your content cutted ? Could you link a screenshot about it ?

You didn't talk about your constraints, did you set yours correctly ?
For example, you can set them like that for :

- UITableView: [image: UITableView constraints]
- UIButton: [image: UITableView constraints]

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, your link show a specific usage of UIScrollView options (Paging), but it is not the default behavior of this component.
Here is an example: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/